# Why I got reloading with a POST to json-server

Tags: javascript, post, json-server

I'm testing the **json-server** package with the following HTML, so my problem is the next one:
**My page reload after I click on `My button`**

I'm trying with a POST request but I don't understand why after the POST, my page reloads.

```
<script>function test(){
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/sessions/',{
    method:'POST',
    mode:'no-cors'
  })
  console.log('Success')
}
</script>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <button type="button" onclick="test()">My button</button>
</body>
```

Even, when I change the request method to GET, the page doesn't reload when I click on that button.

I think that the problem is related to **json-server** because when I make POST request to other APIs, my page doesn't reload, but I'm not sure why. Somebody could help me

Comment: What network says? Go to your Browser Dev Tools, open the `Network` tab, check `Preserve log` and try to press the button. Your server should respond with code 200.

Comment: Yest, it does. The response is 200, but after getting the response, my page reloads

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Live Server extension? For some weird reason it causes all requests but 'GET' to reload the page. Try disabling that and you shoukd be fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31709567)

Comment: Yeah, please clarify!!!